# How to set the schedule to Google Calendar from google-api-go-client?

Tags: go, google-calendar-api, google-api-go-client

I wanna set the schedule to google calendar from [google-api-go-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client).

I got tired set the schedule with google calendar application :(

Is there any sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quicksstart for Google Calendar API. The detail information is https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/go.

And when you want to create events, you can use "Events: insert". You can see the detail [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert).

It seems that you live in Japan. So when you use sample script, please be careful for `DateTime` and `TimeZone`.

If you use above both samples, `main()` becomes as follows. Before run sample script, please confirm whether Google Calendar API is enabled at Google API console. `DateTime` and `TimeZone` are for Japan. Please check above document sites about the detail.

**Script :**

```
func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("client_secret.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/calendar-go-quickstart.json
    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, calendar.CalendarScope)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(ctx, config)
    srv, err := calendar.New(client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve calendar Client %v", err)
    }

    event := &calendar.Event{
        Summary:     "Sample event",
        Location:    "Sample location",
        Description: "This is a sample event.",
        Start: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: "2017-04-22T00:00:00+09:00",
            TimeZone: "Asia/Tokyo",
        },
        End: &calendar.EventDateTime{
            DateTime: "2017-04-22T01:00:00+09:00",
            TimeZone: "Asia/Tokyo",
        },
    }
    calendarID := "#####"
    event, err = srv.Events.Insert(calendarID, event).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to create event. %v\n", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Event created: %s\n", event.HtmlLink)
}
```

Comment: Sorry.
Was my English wrong? :(

Thanks. I try this code.
Take care of `DateTime` and `TimeZone`.

Comment: What do you mean? If I have misunderstood your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: You say "It seems that you live in Japan". I thought that my English was wrong.

Comment: I see. Thank you for using me

Comment: Don't worry. Also I have no room to talk about English skill. If you have problems for above script, feel free to tell me.

Comment: I have a question. Where is the  `getClient` function defined?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142243/discussion-between-junya-kono-and-tanaike).

Comment: At first, let me ask you about your condition for running script.